Save number of total search query count on models in Django
Below is my Django code to save user searches on database. How can I implement a function that when a same user searches same keywords for multiple time I need to record count of that keywords on database if its logged in user or session user
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not search_keywords.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, search_word=query).exists():
                search_keywords.objects.create(
                    user = self.request.user,
                    search_word = query,
                    session_id = session_id
                )
        else:
            if not search_keywords.objects.filter(session_id=session_id, search_word=query).exists():
                search_keywords.objects.get_or_create(
                    session_id=session_id,
                    search_word = query,
                )

        search_vector = (
            SearchVector('title', weight='A') +
            SearchVector('description', weight='B') +
        )
        search_query = SearchQuery(query)
        return items.objects.annotate(
            rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
        ).filter(rank__gt=0.1).order_by('-rank')
    return items.objects.none()


Share the search_keywords model.

class search_keywords(models.Model):     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)     searched_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)     search_word = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)     session_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)      count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

Please [edit] your question to include the comment.

Increase the count with:
from django.db.models import F


def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            search = {'user': self.request.user, 'search_word': query}
        else:
            search = {'search_word': query}
        search['session_id'] = session_id
        updated = search_keywords.objects.filter(**search).update(
            count=F('count') + 1
        )
        if not updated:
            search_keywords.objects.create(**search)
        search_vector = (
            SearchVector('title', weight='A'),
            SearchVector('description', weight='B'),
        )
        search_query = SearchQuery(query)
        return (
            items.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query))
            .filter(rank__gt=0.1)
            .order_by('-rank')
        )
    return items.objects.none()

great, it's adding count but rather than updating the count for the same query it's not updating the count
